# I'm trying to make a question prompt, but It wont load in the prompt due to syntax error

Tags: javascript, prompt

I'm trying to make this put up an alert when answering the first prompt, can anyone help?

```
var answer = "Griffin"
var answer2 = "griffin"

if(prompt("What's your name?"))
{
    if(answer === ("Griffin"))
    {
        var callback = function() {
            alert("Oh hi! " + answer)
    }
    }
} else {
    if(answer2 === ("griffin"))
  {
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
   } else {
            alert("Then whats your name if it's not Griffin?")
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi , i think you meant === instead of =, you can use https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp to view the documentation and test the code live.

Comment: The syntax error is because of the `;` in`if (answer2 = ("griffin"));`

Comment: You have a `;` in you if statements.

Comment: remove semicolon in if condtion

Comment: The `=` is also a problem, but not a syntax error.

Comment: `=` is assginment, `==` and `===` are comparisons (use `===`).

Answer (score 0):

remove the semicolon in the if-statement and use comparator operator(==) instead of assign operator(=) in if-statment

here is the updated code

```
 var answer = 'Griffin';
var answer2 = 'griffin';

if (prompt("What's your name?")) {
  if ((answer == 'Griffin')) {
    var callback = function () {
      alert('Oh hi! ' + answer);
    };
  }
} else {
  if ((answer2 == 'griffin')) {
    setTimeout(callback, 1000);
  } else {
    alert("Then whats your name if it's not Griffin?");
  }
}
```

Comment: You also need to change the `=` to `===`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the single equals in the if blocks with a triple equal. In this case, you assign the value instead of checking it and also remove the semicolon in the first if, before the executing block;

Later edit:
Your question is not that clear, so I try to update the answer somehow accordingly.

```
var userAnswer = prompt("What's your name?"); // keep a reference to what user types in

switch (userAnswer) {
  case 'Griffin':
    // do something, alert, etc
    alert("Oh hi! " + userAnswer);
    break;
  case 'griffin':
    // do something else
    alert("Oh hi! griffin");
    break;
  default:
    // if none of the above cases are matched
    alert("Then what's your name if it's not Griffin?");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Omg Thank you!!

Comment: Feel free to mark the question as solved if the answer fixed your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = "Griffin"
var answer2 = "griffin"

var verify = prompt("What's your name?")

if (verify == answer) {
  callback()
}
else if
    (verify == answer2) {
    alert("Oh hi! " + answer2)
}
else {
    alert("Then whats your name if it's not Griffin?")
}

function callback(){
    alert("Oh hi! " + answer)
}
```

Comment: Another way .....hope it helps you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
    var answer = "Griffin"
    var answer2 = "griffin"
//here  we need variable ,it will hold the prompt input.. 
    var promptInput = prompt("what is your name?")

    if (promptInput == "Griffin") {
            var callback = function call() {
            alert("Oh hi! " + answer)
        }
        callback();//if it is "Griffin" it is going to call the function which is callback()
    }
    else if (promptInput == "griffin") {
        setTimeout(callback, 1000);
    }
    else {
        alert("Then whats your name if it's not Griffin?")
         }
```